# Rethinkdb: how to call getAll with array of predefined ids

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdbdash

Have some ids:

```
let uIds = ['2e56c685-977b-41df-95dd-6adab3aef009', 
  'dc636c8c-46b8-4022-bea8-a17e692e75ce'
  ];
```

How to get all records with these ids?

This doesn't work:

```
r.db('test').table('users').getAll(uIds)
```

And this too:

```
r.db('test').table('users').getAll.apply(this, uIds)
```

And even this:

```
r.db('test').table('users').getAll(r.expr(uIds))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `r.args` to splice arguments:

.getAll(r.args(uIds))

If those arguments are known when building the query, you can also use `apply` , but it must be called with the proper `this` argument:

```
var table = r.table('users');
table.getAll.apply(table, uIds)
```